# Calling an InternalCall Method

Tags: .net

I saw a method in reference source I want to use, but it's marked as `MethodImplOptions.InternalCall`. I copied the code from reference source into my project, but it throws `TypeLoadException` with "Internal call method with non_NULL RVA". How do I call an internal method from my code?

Answer (score 1):

That is normally handled by the JIT and/or runtime. You cant create your own methods with `InternalCall`.

You can just however call it directly (or via reflection/delegate) from where it is specified.